# Click on button and a randomly pictures show in full screen

Tags: java, android

```
       int[] cards={R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2};
    Random r = new Random();
    int n=r.nextInt(7);
```

Someone know if this is right code to click on button and release random pictures in fullscreen, ?

Comment: Yes. This is not the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing in your code is just getting one random number and saving in a variable, also R.drawable.img is just a reference to the image not the image itself so your code is wrong.

Comment: Also the generated random number has nothing to do with the number of images.